# Error on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

after deploying my app on heroku,when i try to sign up on the app,i get this page from heroku

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

my log file is this

```
-----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby

-----> Ruby app detected

-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails

-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0

###### WARNING:

       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.

       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.

       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.

       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.

       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7

       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4

       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........

       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...

       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

       Resolving dependencies...

       Rubygems 2.0.14.1 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.

       Installing rake 10.4.2

       Installing i18n 0.7.0

       Installing json 1.8.3

       Installing minitest 5.8.3

       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5

       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2

       Installing activesupport 4.2.4

       Installing builder 3.2.2

       Installing erubis 2.7.0

       Installing mini_portile2 2.0.0

       Installing nokogiri 1.6.7.1

       Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3

       Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7

       Installing loofah 2.0.3

       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2

       Installing actionview 4.2.4

       Installing rack 1.6.4

       Installing rack-test 0.6.3

       Installing actionpack 4.2.4

       Installing globalid 0.3.6

       Installing activejob 4.2.4

       Installing mime-types 2.99

       Installing mail 2.6.3

       Installing actionmailer 4.2.4

       Installing activemodel 4.2.4

       Installing arel 6.0.3

       Installing activerecord 4.2.4

       Installing pg 0.18.4

       Installing activerecord-postgresql-adapter 0.0.1

       Installing execjs 2.6.0

       Installing autoprefixer-rails 6.2.1

       Installing bcrypt 3.1.10

       Installing sass 3.4.20

       Installing bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.2

       Using bundler 1.9.7

       Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0

       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1

       Installing thor 0.19.1

       Installing railties 4.2.4

       Installing coffee-rails 4.1.1

       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.0

       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0

       Installing responders 2.1.1

       Installing warden 1.2.4

       Installing devise 3.5.3

       Installing multi_json 1.11.2

       Installing jbuilder 2.3.2

       Installing jquery-rails 4.0.5

       Installing password_strength 1.1.1

       Installing sprockets 3.5.2

       Installing sprockets-rails 3.0.0

       Installing rails 4.2.4

       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4

       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.4

       Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3

       Installing tilt 2.0.1

       Installing sass-rails 5.0.4

       Installing simple_form 3.2.1

       Installing turbolinks 2.5.3

       Installing uglifier 2.7.2

       Installing will_paginate 3.0.7

       Installing will_paginate-bootstrap 1.0.1

       Bundle complete! 20 Gemfile dependencies, 62 gems now installed.

       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.

       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.

       Bundle completed (52.05s)

       Cleaning up the bundler cache.

-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline

       Running: rake assets:precompile

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:04.534075 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/futo-e4861dc21d4f262c7d71f5a7485df89a9766ef9010d301950b49070a0a3bb67e.jpg

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:04.536994 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/header-212dcd3c416ad94c32cdd01d58ed1c613374c139de20215783e057c54f93af64.jpg

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:06.814030 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/application-7ec857240036347e31e43de6607d10195206514a27809edbabaac2cbb7e33a2c.js

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:06.814357 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/application-7ec857240036347e31e43de6607d10195206514a27809edbabaac2cbb7e33a2c.js.gz

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:13.868142 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/application-2976e5261a35a755c4b539f86ad52435d2609ef6b8f7dfa41759505bca725188.css

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:13.868470 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/application-2976e5261a35a755c4b539f86ad52435d2609ef6b8f7dfa41759505bca725188.css.gz

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:13.869235 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-f495f34e4f177cf0115af995bbbfeb3fcabc88502876e76fc51a4ab439bc8431.eot

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:13.870405 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-fc969dc1c6ff531abcf368089dcbaf5775133b0626ff56b52301a059fc0f9e1e.woff

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:13.871564 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-bd18efd3efd70fec8ad09611a20cdbf99440b2c1d40085c29be036f891d65358.ttf

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:13.872573 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-d168d50a88c730b4e6830dc0da2a2b51dae4658a77d9619943c27b8ecfc19d1a.svg

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:13.873371 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-d168d50a88c730b4e6830dc0da2a2b51dae4658a77d9619943c27b8ecfc19d1a.svg.gz

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:13.947930 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/index-fa812812183a74cbeb7cead19cf81fd3f19c2ef9737e0795ca6e292e9880fc67.css

       I, [2015-12-24T11:22:13.948537 #1003]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_5a632118a67ee197ead18c935b980da8/public/assets/index-fa812812183a74cbeb7cead19cf81fd3f19c2ef9737e0795ca6e292e9880fc67.css.gz

       Asset precompilation completed (11.27s)

       Cleaning assets

       Running: rake assets:clean
###### WARNING:

       Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform features

       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems for more information.
###### WARNING:

       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.

       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:

       ruby '2.0.0'

       # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.
###### WARNING:

       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.

       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.

       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.

       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.

       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
###### WARNING:

       No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)

       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
-----> Discovering process types

       Procfile declares types     -> (none)

       Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web, worker
-----> Compressing... done, 30.0MB

-----> Launching... done, v12

       https://limitless-eyrie-2483.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: You should check your logs with `heroku logs`. Likely you just forgot to run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: already ran migration @ sevenseacat

Comment: Did you check your logs to see what the error was?

Comment: i see an error  'awaiting client' and also 'state changed from starting to up'

Comment: should i run 'bundle exec rake db:migrate' ?

Comment: Add your logs to the question and we may be able to help you solve the problem.

Comment: It is no tech problem. On HEROKU free plan You can use only sandbox. Please, see https://www.heroku.com/pricing

Comment: @СергійНазаревич You are incorrect, it *is* a tech problem. That error is being raised by the Rails application for a reason we are yet to see.

Comment: I get this error on my log "fatal signalException" SIGTERM" don't know if its the error here.

Answer (score -4):

May be You have to change better Heroku using plan. (Not sandbox!)
With this errors I moved to AmazonWS... :)

UPDATE:
This is an accurate answer to the question. Some time ago I had exactly the same problem. Heroku `free` only as sandbox. If You try use `free Heroku` from public internet, You will see message as ChrisGeek wrote. So one solution -- move to other Cloud, for example AmazonWS EC2. When I move my project WITHOUT ANY CHANGING to AWS --- it work properly. On HEROKU minimal plan for using from public internet -- 7$ per month, but all they's ad. say -- "we are free".

Comment: This at best has nothing to do with the question, and at worst is totally misleading. Heroku free apps are still publicly accessible, and I know because I have several of them myself.